# Browsing IPv6 only

Tags: ipv6

I would like to check some websites by using IPv6 only: not only connecting with an IPv6 address but also checking that every other following connection (e.g., for embedded content with iframes) is performed with IPv6.

Is there a browser where I can disable IPv4? Or a proxy I can install?

Comment: One of the key points of the modern network-stack is that higher levels in the stack do not depend on the underlying layer: a web-browser, or any application, is ignorant of the underlying transport protocol and again that is ignorant of the underlying physical medium. This would not be a web-browser option, you would instead configure your network-stack to route everything over IPv6 interfaces.

Comment: Yes but maybe there is a proxy resolving every DNS query by looking at AAAA records only.

Comment: I also did not find any way to temporarily disable IPv4 on OS X

Comment: You'd have to go to your network adapter settings and turn IPv4 off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable IPv4 in your OS and adding some public DNS64/NAT64-Resolver.
You can create your own IPv6-only-environment:
Apple has prepared such an environment for testing purposes.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1

Answer (score 1):

You can turn IPv4 off in Setting -> Network -> Advanced -> TCP/IP -> Configure IPv4 -> Off.

Answer (score -2):

Use Firefox Browser! It can be input ipv6 address on URL blank. If you have bookmark made by IPv6 address, Firefox Browser will work on IPv6 address.

Comment: I am not sure how this answers the question - can you elaborate?

Comment: Any browser supports the URL with IPv6 addresses, the question is how to force it for every further connection (for example for embedded resources)